# pubnub + react-native not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, pubnub

I am trying to get pubnub working with react-native. I installed pubnub with npm, but when I try to subscribe to a channel I receive the error 'method GET must not have a request body'. If I just try to run this code outside of react-native in node it works perfectly. If I turn the code into an async action it doesn't throw the get method error, but nothing happens and I don't receive the 'Here' console.log indicating a successful connection.

https://dpaste.de/F7LR

Comment: We received your support inquiry. We'll review and respond there and once we have solid answer we'll post back here. Cheers!

Comment: Try upgrading: engineering has addressed this in v4.10.0
https://www.pubnub.com/docs/react-native-javascript/pubnub-javascript-sdk

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by downgrading pubnub to 4.7.0